# Conditional expectation example and sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to get $E(X|F)$. But I am not sure if I am right.

The only single variables available in $F$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{ 2\}$. So, the probability of 2 possible events out of 6 events in F is $\frac{2}{6}=1/3$.

Am I right? If not right, how do we get $ E(X|F)$ ? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.
$F=\sigma(\{1 \},\{2 \},\{3,4 \})$

$D=\{ \{1 \},\{2 \},\{3,4 \} \}$

$$E(X|F)=E(X|\{1\})1_{\{1 \}} +E(X|\{2\})1_{\{2 \}}+E(X|\{3,4\})1_{\{3,4 \}}
$$

On the other hands

\begin{eqnarray}
E(X|F)(\omega)= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
E(X|\{1\})   &  \omega \in \{1 \} \\
E(X|\{2\})   &  \omega \in \{2 \}\\
E(X|\{3,4\})   &  \omega \in \{3,4 \}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
see 
[conditional-expectations-when-conditioning-on-a-discrete-sigma-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156175/conditional-expectations-when-conditioning-on-a-discrete-sigma-algebra)
 and [a finite or countable partition](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall17/sta711/lec/wk-10.pdf)
now

$$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X1_{A})}{P(A)}$$  [Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event)

for example

$$E(X|\{3,4\})=\frac{E(X1_{\{3,4\}})}{P(\{3,4\})}$$